# On the arguments of 'put'

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, complements

I have noticed that the verb 'put' usually takes a direct object and a (typically) prepositional, non-core complement, as in:

> He put the book on the shelf

Sometimes, the prepositional complement is replaced by an adverb:

> He put the book away.

My question is: is the adverb here a predicative complement, or a non-core complement?

Comment: _Put away_ is a phrasal verb (*_He put away it_), so _away_ is a particle, or an adverb, or a preposition, or whatever your syntactic religion says that the non-verbal parts of phrasal verbs are sposta be called. Probly not a complement, though people will call practically anything a complement, I've found.

Comment: Since *put away* is a phrasal verb — *He put the book away. He put away the book about cats.* — A better example for your question might be *He put the book upstairs.*

Comment: "Away" is a particle, the only **complement** that can freely come between a verb and its direct object. In your example, it's complement of "put". I recall that you have access to CGEL, so I suggest you take a look therein where it's all explained.

Comment: Incidentally, despite the comments above, I strongly suggest you avoid using the term 'phrasal verb'. It's a misnomer, since it's not the whole "put away" that is a verb but only the lexeme "put".